# odas web results an error "sink pots: cannot connect to server" when executed

Tags: node.js, npm, hardware

I'm trying to use odas_web with Respeaker Mic Array V2.0 to perform sound source localization and tracking. When odas is launched after setting the corresponding config file, GUI doesn't provide any data (it remains as it is!).

Also when I execute the command "./odaslive -c ./ -v"  , it results in  the following error;

> "sink pots: cannot connect to server"

The config file I used is:

```
# Configuration file for XMOS circular sound card

version = "2.1";

# Raw

raw: 
{
    fS = 16000;
    hopSize = 128;
    nBits = 16;
    nChannels = 6; 

    # Input with raw signal from microphones
    interface: {
        type = "soundcard";
        card = 1;
        device = 0;
    }
}

# Mapping

mapping:
{
    map: (2, 3, 4, 5);
}

# General

general:
{
    epsilon = 1E-20;

    size: 
    {
        hopSize = 128;
        frameSize = 256;
    };

    samplerate:
    {
        mu = 16000;
        sigma2 = 0.01;
    };

    speedofsound:
    {
        mu = 343.0;
        sigma2 = 25.0;
    };

    mics = (

        # Microphone 2
        { 
            mu = ( -0.032, +0.000, +0.000 ); 
            sigma2 = ( +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000 );
            direction = ( +0.000, +0.000, +1.000 );
            angle = ( 80.0, 100.0 );
        },

        # Microphone 3
        { 
            mu = ( +0.000, -0.032, +0.000 ); 
            sigma2 = ( +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000 );
            direction = ( +0.000, +0.000, +1.000 );
            angle = ( 80.0, 100.0 );
        },

        # Microphone 4
        { 
            mu = ( +0.032, +0.000, +0.000 ); 
            sigma2 = ( +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000 );
            direction = ( +0.000, +0.000, +1.000 );
            angle = ( 80.0, 100.0 );
        },

        # Microphone 5
        { 
            mu = ( +0.000, +0.032, +0.000 ); 
            sigma2 = ( +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000, +0.000 );
            direction = ( +0.000, +0.000, +1.000 );
            angle = ( 80.0, 100.0 );        
        }
    );

    # Spatial filter to include only a range of direction if required
    # (may be useful to remove false detections from the floor)
    spatialfilters = (

        {
            direction = ( +0.000, +0.000, +1.000 );
            angle = (80.0, 100.0);
        }    
    );

    nThetas = 181;
    gainMin = 0.25;
};

# Stationnary noise estimation

sne:
{
    b = 3;
    alphaS = 0.1;
    L = 150;
    delta = 3.0;
    alphaD = 0.1;
}

# Sound Source Localization

ssl:
{
    nPots = 4;
    nMatches = 10;
    probMin = 0.5;
    nRefinedLevels = 1;
    interpRate = 4;

    # Number of scans: level is the resolution of the sphere
    # and delta is the size of the maximum sliding window
    # (delta = -1 means the size is automatically computed)
    scans = (
        { level = 2; delta = -1; },
        { level = 4; delta = -1; }
    );

    # Output to export potential sources
    potential: {

        # format = "undefined";
        format = "json";

        interface: {
            # type = "blackhole";
            type = "socket";
        ip = "127.0.0.1";
        port = 9001;
        };
    };
};

# Sound Source Tracking

sst:
{
    # Mode is either "kalman" or "particle"

    mode = "kalman";

    # Add is either "static" or "dynamic"

    add = "dynamic";    

    # Parameters used by both the Kalman and particle filter

    active = (
        { weight = 1.0; mu = 0.4; sigma2 = 0.0025 }
    );

    inactive = (
        { weight = 1.0; mu = 0.25; sigma2 = 0.0025 }
    );

    sigmaR2_prob = 0.0025;
    sigmaR2_active = 0.0225;
    sigmaR2_target = 0.0025;
    Pfalse = 0.1;
    Pnew = 0.1;
    Ptrack = 0.8;

    theta_new = 0.9;
    N_prob = 5;
    theta_prob = 0.8;
    N_inactive = ( 250, 250, 250, 250 );
    theta_inactive = 0.9;

    # Parameters used by the Kalman filter only

    kalman: {

        sigmaQ = 0.001;

    };

    # Parameters used by the particle filter only

    particle: {

        nParticles = 1000;
        st_alpha = 2.0;
        st_beta = 0.04;
        st_ratio = 0.5;
        ve_alpha = 0.05;
        ve_beta = 0.2;
        ve_ratio = 0.3;
        ac_alpha = 0.5;
        ac_beta = 0.2;
        ac_ratio = 0.2;
        Nmin = 0.7;

    };

    target: ();

    # Output to export tracked sources
    tracked: {

        format = "json";

        interface: {
            # type = "file";
            # path = "tracks.txt";
            type = "socket";
        ip = "127.0.0.1";
        port = 9000;
        };
    };
}

sss:
{
    # Mode is either "dds", "dgss" or "dmvdr"

    mode_sep = "dgss";
    mode_pf = "ms";

    gain_sep = 1.0;
    gain_pf = 10.0;

    dds: {

    };

    dgss: {

        mu = 0.01;
        lambda = 0.5;

    };

    dmvdr: {

    };

    ms: {

        alphaPmin = 0.07;
        eta = 0.5;
        alphaZ = 0.8;        
        thetaWin = 0.3;
        alphaWin = 0.3;
        maxAbsenceProb = 0.9;
        Gmin = 0.01;
        winSizeLocal = 3;
        winSizeGlobal = 23;
        winSizeFrame = 256;

    };

    ss: {

        Gmin = 0.01;
        Gmid = 0.9;
        Gslope = 10.0;

    };

    separated: {

        fS = 16000;
        hopSize = 128;
        nBits = 16;        

        interface: {
            #type = "file";
            #path = "separated.raw";
        type = "socket";
        ip = "127.0.0.1";
        port = 10000;
        };        

    };

    postfiltered: {

        fS = 16000;
        hopSize = 128;
        nBits = 16;        
        gain = 10.0;

        interface: {
            #type = "file";
            #path = "postfiltered.raw";
        type = "socket";
        ip = "127.0.0.1";
        port = 10010;
        };        
    };
};

classify:
{

    frameSize = 4096;
    winSize = 3;
    tauMin = 88;
    tauMax = 551;
    deltaTauMax = 20;
    alpha = 0.3;
    gamma = 0.05;
    phiMin = 0.5;
    r0 = 0.2;    

    category: {

        format = "undefined";

        interface: {
            type = "blackhole";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it affects your config, but the correct English spelling for _Stationnary_ is _Stationary_.

Answer (score 0):

Its mean, odas is started and cannot locate socket server at  ip = "127.0.0.1";
    port = 9001;
or set for send potential sources address in the local network, where already running web part of odas like

```
potential: {

        format = "json";
        interface: {
            type = "socket";
            ip = "192.168.0.102";
            port = 9001;
        };
```

or set like this:

```
potential: {

        format = "json"; 
        interface: {
             type = "file";
path = "potential.json"; 
        };

    };
```

to save found potentials to file, for future debug